# Using a caliper in PSM (R's Matchit package) changed matching and made balance worse, even though number of matched treatment remained the same?

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

**I figured out the answer to this... refer to the answer I posted below.**

**A) My knowledge of what a caliper does (please correct if wrong):**

Adding a caliper (e.g caliper = 0.2) when matching using R's matchit package, means only matching a control group point and a treatment group point if they are within 0.2 standard deviations (of propensity score in this case) away from each other. Therefore treatment group points without control group points within 0.2 s.d will not be matched, and hence discarded. This is supposed to improve balance (reduce bias), as it produces matched control and treatment only if they are "similar" enough with each other.

**B) My main Question:**

So, with resampling (replace = TRUE), and using nearest neighbour method, doesn't this mean including a caliper can only change the matching by reducing the number of treatment groups matched, and potentially the number of control group points used for matching?

I.e Treatment group points WITH a control group point within 0.2 sd will be matched the same way as without a caliper (assuming seed is constant), by being matched with it's nearest neighbour. Treatment group points those WITHOUT a control group point within 0.2 sd will be discarded.

In the following example, this is not what happened, so I'm very confused. Any explanations / correction of my understanding of calipers would be greatly appreciated!

**C) Example to my question above:**

In the following example (Code taken from https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/statistics/tutorial8.html), I ran PSM with a caliper and without a caliper, both times all my treatment group points were matched (1352). So I'd expect it means the caliper had no effect (as it didn't prevent any treatment group points from getting matched), and therefore the control group points matched should be the same.

BUT that was not the case. Without a caliper, number of control group points matched = 1164, with a caliper, it increased to 1185, as a result changing my estimate of the effect of treatment. It also seems to have made balance worse (as seen from the images, link attached). Could someone please explain to me how this could have happened?

**Without a caliper**, I got the following results (Matched Control = 1164, Matched Treated 1352):

```
Call: 
matchit(formula = catholic ~ race_white + w3income + p5hmage + 
    p5numpla + w3momed_hsb, data = ecls_nomiss, method = "nearest", 
    distance = "logit", replace = TRUE)

Sample sizes:
          Control Treated
All          7915    1352
Matched      1164    1352
Unmatched    6751       0
Discarded       0       0
```

Effect of treatment (being a catholic), using linear regression = -0.176:

```
Call:
lm(formula = c5r2mtsc_std ~ catholic, data = dta_m)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4783 -0.5803  0.0647  0.5997  3.0473 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.38637    0.02677  14.432  < 2e-16 ***
catholic    -0.17670    0.03652  -4.838 1.39e-06 ***
```

Balance (by comparing each covariance of control and treatment across propensity score), seems to be very well matched:
[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyU6s.png

**With a caliper**, I got the following results (Matched Control = 1185, Matched Treated 1352):

```
Call: 
matchit(formula = catholic ~ race_white + w3income + p5hmage + 
    p5numpla + w3momed_hsb, data = ecls_nomiss, method = "nearest", 
    distance = "logit", replace = TRUE, caliper = 0.2)

Sample sizes:
          Control Treated
All          7915    1352
Matched      1185    1352
Unmatched    6730       0
Discarded       0       0
```

Estimate of effect of treatment = -0.1151, i.e it reduced:

```
Call:
lm(formula = c5r2mtsc_std ~ catholic, data = dta_m)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4167 -0.5649  0.0608  0.5947  3.1089 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.32477    0.02635  12.326  < 2e-16 ***
catholic    -0.11510    0.03609  -3.189  0.00144 **
```

Balance (by comparing each covariance of control and treatment across propensity score), seems to have gotten worse, and matching between control and treatment also got worse:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uLK.png

Answer (score 2):

Just checked the R documentation --- **If a caliper is specified, a control
unit within the caliper for a treated unit is randomly selected as the match for that treated unit.**  So this explains it all, it selects the matching control unit randomly.

When I set caliper = 0.0000001, balance improved. So turns out caliper = 0.2 was too big for my dataset.

Comment: FYI this behavior has changed as of version 4.0.0. The closest unit is now chosen as a match when a caliper is specified (as when it is not).