# R: Propensity Score Matching keep all matches in caliper

Tags: r, tidyverse, match, propensity-score-matching

I am doing propensity score matching using R's `MatchIt` library. I have more potential control units than treated units and I want to match using a caliper with replacement. As I understand from [here](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/news/index.html#:%7E:text=When%20using%20method%20%3D%20%22nearest%22%20with%20a%20caliper%20specified%2C%20the%20nearest%20control%20unit%20will%20be%20matched%20to%20the%20treated%20unit%20if%20one%20is%20available.%20Previously%2C%20a%20random%20control%20unit%20within%20the%20caliper%20would%20be%20selected.%20This%20eliminates%20the%20need%20for%20the%20calclosest%20argument%2C%20which%20has%20been%20removed.) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63260512/8772574), `MatchIt`'s caliper option defines the boundary of interest and then matches only the nearest neighbor within the caliper.

***Request***: I want to retain ***all*** matched units within the caliper. Is there a way to do this with `MatchIt::matchit` or is there another implementation that I can use? I don't want the "nearest neighbor" step after the units within the caliper have been defined.

The code below is similar to my data and shows how the control N is bounded above by the number of treated units. Any guidance would be immensly helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MatchIt)

# load data
data("lalonde")

# specify propensity score formula
pscore_lhs_vars <- c(str_subset(names(lalonde), 'treat', negate=T))
pscore_formula <- as.formula(paste('treat~', paste(pscore_lhs_vars, collapse = "+")))

# perform match with replacement using a caliper in units
matches<- lalonde %>% matchit(pscore_formula, 
                    data=., 
                    method='nearest', 
                    distance='glm', 
                    replace=T, 
                    std.caliper = T, 
                    caliper=(pscore=0.0000001))
# return matched data
match.data(matches, distance='pscore')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `ratio` to be a huge number (i.e., the number of control units). This will retain all units within a treated unit's caliper. Any treated unit that doesn't have that many matches in its caliper will simply be matched to as many as there are.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful package. I understand that I could set ratio=some large number and the results converge in the limit, are there any plans to add a more options for how to select within the caliper?

Comment: @JRR not sure what other options you're thinking about. Feel free to submit a feature request on the package's issues page.